# Change the Content of Table Column by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code generated by apex

```
<td class="dataCol last " colspan="2">
  <ul title="Error! " style="color:red">
    <li>    Account Name: You must enter a value </li>
    <li>    Email: You must enter a value </li>
    <li>    User Name: You must enter a value </li>
    <li>    Contact Name: Validation Error: Value is required. </li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

I want to replace the whole content with just a simple text "Error! Values Required" means i dont want this  tag .

My jquery code is given below but its doesnt work, kindly make correction if possible

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.dataCol.last ').each(function() {

         var lastColumn = $(this).html();
         var replaceValue = "Error! Value Required";

        jQuery(this).html(replaceValue );
        });
  });       
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing $ with jQuery variable? Do not do that!

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console otherwise your code should work... http://jsfiddle.net/Hf3YY/

Comment: TypeError: $(...) is null
$('.dataCol.last').html("Error! Value Required");

Comment: why dont you try  `$('.dataCol')` instead of `$('.dataCol.last')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.dataCol.last ').each(function() {

    // var lastColumn = $(this).html();
     //var replaceValue = "Error! Value Required";

    jQuery(this).html("<ul><li>Error! Value Required</li></ul>" );
    });
 });       
</script>
```

I have refined you code ,it should work as you intended :)

BTW why have you used `jQuery.noConflict();` in your code, are you trying to use more than one Jquery lib in your page ?

Comment: noConflict isn't used for "more than one jQuery lib" but "more than one JavaScript lib using $"

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dataCol').html('Error! Value Required');
});
```

try this one

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the whole content of that `td`, try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dataCol.last").html("Error! Value Required");
});
```

Comment: it doesnt works for me Jude.. still it display the whole <ul> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dataCol").html("error");
});
```

Comment: i have got multiple column with id dataCol, it unique id is class="dataCol last "